# How to control "Ajax" using selenium web driver?

Tags: ajax, selenium, web, selenium-webdriver

i am not able to select value from drop down list on page load.

I am using Implicitly Timeout option in this code:

```
driver.manage.timeout(100,timeunit.Millisecond);
driver.findelement(By.id("valueID")).click();
```

Answer (score 2):

[presenceOfElementLocated](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#presenceOfElementLocated%28org.openqa.selenium.By%29) does not assure that element is either clickable or even visible. From the doc:

```
An expectation for checking that an element is present on the DOM of a page.
```

You should use either [elementToBeClickable](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#elementToBeClickable%28org.openqa.selenium.By%29) or [visibilityOfElementLocated](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#visibilityOfElementLocated%28org.openqa.selenium.By%29)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to replying you all:

I found a solution in this case:

**

```
WebElement web = driver.findElement(By.id(ID));
Select clickonthis = new Select(web);
clickonthis.selectByVisibleText("Bombay")
```

**